# Почему дёргается позиция горизонтального скролла Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

В Angular компоненте при изменении позиции горизонтального скроллбара мышкой скролл начинает прыгать, изменяя свою позицию на плюс/минус десять пикселей. Были предположения, что это может происходить из-за частых перерисовок. В чём может быть проблема?

Скроллбар задаётся следующими стилями: `overflow-x: auto;`

Браузер: Google Chrome (версия 109.0.5414.75)

Объём потребляемой памяти вкладкой - 294820K, загрузка ЦПУ - 74.2%.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась с помощью добавления стратегии обнаружения изменений `OnPush`.